# Combine two pieces of regex

Tags: .net, regex

I need to combine two pieces of regex. One that checks that the start of the string is `http://` or `https://` and one that prevent commas.

```
ValidationExpression="(\b(http://|https://)\S*)?"

ValidationExpression="[^,]"
```

Just adding them together doesn't seem to work.

```
ValidationExpression="(\b(http://|https://)[^,]\S*)?"
```

**EDIT**
I realize I was a bit vague here. Yes, I want the whole expression to be optional (this field should be optional in my form)

Comment: I think the [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) at the start is unnecessary since the regex will be applied to the full string, won't it? Also, is it your intention to make the entire expression optional?

Comment: Yes, the whole expression should be optional.

Comment: Making an entire field optional should not be done through Regex. You could easily do that through trivial string functions like `IsNullOrEmpty()` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), and you don't need the alternation when a simple `?` will do:

```
ValidationExpression="(\bhttps?://[^,\s]*)?"
```

`[^\s]` means the same as `\S`, so `[^,\s]` matches any character that is neither a comma nor a whitespace character.

Answer (score 2):

TRY THIS:
pattern: `^https?://[^,]+$` 
Match:
`ok - http://aaa/bbb/ccc`
`ok - https://aaa/bbb/ccc`
`false - http://aaa/bbb/,/ccc`
`false - https://aaa/bbb/,/ccc`

OR

pattern:
 `https?://[^,]+`

text:
`http://aaa/bbb/,/ccc https://abecadlo/123/`

matches:
`http://aaa/bbb/`
`https://abecadlo/123/`

Answer (score 0):

The expression should more likely be:

```
https?://[^,\s]*
```

You don't probably want to make the entire expression optional, so remove the ? around the entire expression.

Comment: I think having the entire expression optional (i.e. allowing either nothing or a "valid" string) makes more sense than allowing an empty `http://`. But that's just a guess and depends on Niklas' requirements, which are hazy.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri;
bool isValid=Uri.TryCreate(url,UriKind.Absolute,out uri);
if(isValid)//valid
else //invalid
```